# siunitx: bold unit in S-column header

Tags: tables, siunitx, bold

I'm trying to insert a bold unit with `\si` in a tabular header in an S-column. But siunitx simply refuses to set it in bold. It only works if I use another column type (or e.g. `\multicolumn{1}{c}`). What's going on? (Be aware that I braced the header, but I tried also without it).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\sisetup{mode=text,detect-weight}

Works: \textbf{\si{\percent}}

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{S
                S[detect-weight]
                c}
  {\bfseries in \si{\percent}}&
  {\bfseries in \si{\percent}}&
  \bfseries in  \si{\percent} 
  \\                
  50 & 50 & 50 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit: the problem has been resolved by the newest package version.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug which has been resolved in the meantime.